# Evaluation of Mellin transform via contours

Tags: real-analysis, special-functions, mellin-transform

Let $f(x)=\dfrac{a^2}{x^2-a^2}$. I want to evaluate the Mellin transform of this function. Let me denote it ${\cal M}[f]$. What I want is to evaluate $${\cal M}[f](s)=\int_0^\infty dx x^{s-1}\dfrac{a^2}{x^2-a^2}.$$

Looking at the form of the integral and considering previous experience with Fourier transforms, I would consider evaluating this using contours in the complex plane. Still, here the integral runs over $(0,\infty)$ so I'm unsure how to proceed.

Suppose that $a\in \mathbb{R}$. Then the integrand has poles at $x=\pm a$. Having that in mind one possibility that I have considered was to take the contours (where $R > a$)

- $\Gamma_1$: parameterized by $t\mapsto t$ with $t\in [0,a-\epsilon]$;
- $\Gamma_2$: parameterized as $\theta\mapsto a+\epsilon e^{i\theta}$ where $\theta\in [-\pi,0]$;
- $\Gamma_3$: parameterized by $t\mapsto t$ where $t\in [a+\epsilon,R]$;
- $\Gamma_4$: parameterized by $\theta\mapsto Re^{i\theta}$ where $\theta\in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$;
- $\Gamma_5$: parameterized by $t\mapsto i(R-t)$ where $t\in [0,R]$;

Now let $\Gamma$ be obtained by joining all of these contours. There is no pole in the region enclosed by $\Gamma$ and so the integral of $g(z)=z^{s-1}\dfrac{a^2}{z^2-a^2}$ over $\Gamma$ is zero. As a result we have that when we send $R\to \infty$ and $\epsilon\to 0$ the integrals over $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_3$ should sum up to ${\cal M}[f](s)$ and therefore we would have something of the form $${\cal M}[f](s)=-\lim_{R\to \infty}\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\left(\int_{\Gamma_2}g(z)dz+\int_{\Gamma_4}g(z)dz+\int_{\Gamma_5}g(z)dz\right)$$

Still I'm unsure. This seems complicated at first. Is this really the way to evaluate ${\cal M}[f]$? Is there a better way of evaluating this Mellin transform?

Comment: Taking $x = i t$ will change the denominator, but you can take $x = -t$. If you're computing the principal value integral, then
$$\operatorname {v. \! p.} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) dx =
\pi i \operatorname* {Res}_{x = -a} f(x) +
 \pi i \operatorname* {Res}_{x = a} f(x),$$
where $f(x) = x^{s - 1}/(x^2 - a^2)$, $a \in \mathbb R \setminus \{ 0 \}$, $0 < \operatorname {Re} s < 2$ and $x^{s - 1}$ is the analytic continuation from $x \in (0, \infty)$ to $x \in \mathbb C \setminus [0, -i \infty)$. $f(x)$ and $f(-x)$ will differ by a constant factor.

Comment: $\tt Mathematica\ 12.0.0.0$ yields 
$$
-{1 \over 2}\pi\left\vert{a}\right\vert^{s}\color{#f00}{\cot}\left(\pi s \over 2\right)
$$

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the contour integral approach will work. However, I want to suggest another way you can obtain the transform.

Assume $a\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ (Same as you assumed, but without 0 as @Maxim pointed out). Make the change of variables:
$$
\begin{aligned}
x&=|a|t^{1/2}\\
dx &= \frac{|a|}{2}t^{-1/2}dt
\end{aligned}
$$
In this sense, if $t\geq 0$ then $x\geq 0$ also. So that:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{a^2x^{s-1}}{x^2-a^2}dx &= \int \frac{|a|^2x^{s-1}}{x^2-|a|^2}dx=\int \frac{x^{s-1}}{(x/|a|)^2-1}dx \\&= \frac{|a|^{s}}{2}\int t^{\frac{s-1}{2}}(t-1)^{-1}t^{-1/2}dt = -\frac{|a|^{s}}{2}\int t^{\frac{s}{2}-1}(1-t)^{-1}dt
\end{aligned}
$$
Now, recall the definition of the incomplete Beta function:
$$
B(z;\alpha,\beta) = \int_0^zt^{\alpha-1}(1-t)^{\beta-1}dt
$$
Thus, if we consider first the interval $[0,L]$ instead of the whole $[0,\infty)$ we get:
$$
\int_0^L \frac{a^2x^{s-1}}{x^2-a^2}dx = -\frac{|a|^{s}}{2}\int_0^{(L/|a|)^2}t^{\frac{s}{2}-1}(t-1)^{-1}dt = -\frac{|a|^{s}}{2} B\left((L/|a|)^2;\frac{s}{2},0\right)
$$
Now we just need to compute:
$$
\lim_{L\to\infty} -\frac{|a|^{s}}{2} B\left((L/|a|)^2;\frac{s}{2},0\right)
$$
To do so, use this identity from Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function) (which is a simple change of variables):
$$
B(z;\alpha,\beta) = (-1)^\alpha B\left(\frac{z}{z-1};\alpha,1-\alpha-\beta\right)
$$
Applying it:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim_{L\to\infty} -\frac{|a|^{s}}{2} B\left((L/|a|)^2;\frac{s}{2},0\right) &= \lim_{L\to\infty}-\frac{|a|^{s}(-1)^{\frac{s}{2}}}{2} B\left(\frac{(L/|a|)^2}{(L/|a|)^2-1};\frac{s}{2},1-\frac{s}{2}\right)\\ &= -\frac{|a|^{s}(-1)^{\frac{s}{2}}}{2}B\left(1;\frac{s}{2},1-\frac{s}{2}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
And, fortunately, $B(1;\alpha,\beta)=B(\alpha,\beta)$ with $B(\bullet,\bullet)$ the typical beta function:
$$
B(1;\alpha,\beta)=B(\alpha,\beta):=\int_{0}^{1}t^{\alpha-1}(1-t)^{\beta-1}dt = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}
$$
where $\Gamma(\bullet)$ is the Gamma function. Thus,
$$
-\frac{|a|^{s}(-1)^{\frac{s}{2}}}{2}B\left(1;\frac{s}{2},1-\frac{s}{2}\right) = -\frac{|a|^{s}(-1)^{\frac{s}{2}}}{2}\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(1-\frac{s}{2}\right)
$$
since $\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2} + 1-\frac{s}{2}\right) = \Gamma(1)=1$. Now, we can further simply by applying the identity in section 18.4.5 [here](http://dsp-book.narod.ru/HFTSP/8579ch18.pdf):
$$
\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z) = \pi\text{csc}(z)
$$
So that:
$$
-\frac{|a|^{s}(-1)^{\frac{s}{2}}}{2}\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(1-\frac{s}{2}\right) = -(-1)^{\frac{s}{2}}\frac{\pi |a|^{s}}{2}\text{csc}\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)
$$
And we can conclude:
$$
\mathcal{M}\left[\frac{a^2}{x^2-a^2}\right](s) = -(-1)^{\frac{s}{2}}\frac{\pi |a|^{s}}{2}\text{csc}\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)
$$
This coincides with the result from Wolfram alpha [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=MellinTransform%5Ba%5E2%2F%28x%5E2-a%5E2%29%2C%20x%2C%20s%5D.).

Hope this helps!

Comment: If you're assuming that $a \in \mathbb R \setminus \{ 0 \}$, you get a divergent integral. If you're assuming $a \not \in \mathbb R$, then some of the transformations are no longer valid. Consider that the integral (as well as the principal value of the integral for a real $a$) is an even function of $a$, while the rhs of your last formula isn't.

Comment: Thanks @Maxim! So, the OP assumes $a\in\mathbb{R}$ which is what I assumed. I think that most transformations are valid in this case, but I would need to check again. By the fact that you get a divergent integral you mean right from the beginning? Or which particular step you think is not longer valid? If its divergent it would be interesting to understand why wolfram gives the same answer as I give, and what does that taking such Mellin transform means at the end. Also I used standard steps for computing the Mellin transform. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm a little bit confused because actually the Wolfram alpha result reads $$\mathcal{M}\left[\frac{a^2}{x^2-a^2}\right](s)=-\frac{\pi}{2}\left(-\frac{1}{a^2}\right)^{-s/2}\csc\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)$$ which is indeed an even function of $a$.

Comment: Ok, so I modified my answer with the change of my previous comment. If $x=at^{1/2}$ with $a<0$, then the procedure is no longer valid since mapping $t\geq 0$ does not lead to the same integral anymore. Hence, $x=|a|t^{1/2}$ should be ok now. Sorry I missed that, I was just trying to help!

Comment: The previous version was correct for some $a \in \mathbb C \setminus \mathbb R$. The reason is that $t = (x/a)^2$ gives $t$ on a ray in the complex plane. On this ray, one can construct an antiderivative and analyze its behavior at infinity. If $a \in \mathbb R$, then yes, the improper integral $\int_0^\infty x^{s - 1}/(x^2 - a^2) \, dx$ doesn't exist, so it's not clear what is being computed. $t^{s/2 - 1}/(1 - t)$ can't have an antiderivative on $(0, \infty)$, only on $(0, 1)$ and $(1, \infty)$, with logarithmic singularities at $t = 1$.

Comment: Does it exist at least for some $s$?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Take $1/(1 - t)$ as a comparison function and apply the limit comparison test to $\int_{1/2}^1 t^{s/2 - 1}/(1 - t) \, dt$.

Comment: Nice. Then I'll wait to see what the OP says, and see what he expected since he assumed $a$ real. Still Im confused about wolfram's output for $a$ real. Thanks @Maxim!

Comment: W|A doesn't say that $a$ is real, it gives the correct result for $a \in \mathbb C \setminus \mathbb R$. The formula for the p.v. integral for real $a$ is different.

Comment: I get that. The part that confuses me is where wolfram says "Alternate forms assuming a and s are positive" and then outputs $-\frac{1}{2}\pi i^{-s}a^s\text{csc}\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)$ even when the integral shouldn't exist in this case.

Comment: W|A takes the closed form and simplifies it under the assumption that $a > 0$. So we have $e_1 \overset {a \not \in \mathbb R} = e_2 \overset {a > 0} = e_3$. It doesn't mean that $e_1 = e_3$ for some $a$.

Comment: Makes sense. thanks

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
& {\cal M}\bracks{\on{f}}\pars{s} \equiv
\\[2mm] & \bbox[5px,#ffd]{%
\left.{\rm P.V.}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{s - 1}\,{a^{2} \over x^{2} - a^{2}}\,\dd x
\,\right\vert_{\substack{a\ \in\ \mathbb{R} \\[1mm]
\Re(s)\ \in\ (0,2)}}}
\\ & =
\verts{a}^{s}\,\,{\rm P.V.}\int_{0}^{\infty}
{x^{s - 1} \over x^{2} - 1}\,\dd x\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}

---

Lets $\ds{{\cal F} \equiv \oint_{\cal C}{z^{s - 1} \over z^{2} - 1}{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}}$ where $\ds{\cal C}$ is a *key-hole contour* which "takes care" of the $\ds{z^{s - 1}}$-*principal branch*.
\begin{align}
&\mbox{Then,}\ {\cal F} =
\on{Res}\bracks{{z^{s - 1} \over z^{2} - 1}, z = 1} = {1 \over 2}\label{2}\tag{2}
\\[5mm] & \mbox{Moreover,}\\[2mm] &
{\cal F} =
\int_{-\infty}^{0}{\pars{-x}^{s - 1}\expo{\ic\pi\pars{s - 1}} \over \pars{x - 1}\pars{x + 1 + \ic 0^{+}}}{\dd x \over 2\pi\ic} \\[2mm] & +
\int_{0}^{-\infty}{\pars{-x}^{s - 1}\expo{-\ic\pi\pars{s - 1}} \over \pars{x - 1}\pars{x + 1 - \ic 0^{+}}}{\dd x \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] = &
-\expo{\ic\pi s}\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{s - 1} \over \pars{x + 1}\pars{x - 1 - \ic 0^{+}}}{\dd x \over 2\pi\ic}\\[2mm] & +
\expo{-\ic\pi s}\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{s - 1} \over \pars{x + 1}\pars{x - 1 + \ic 0^{+}}}{\dd x \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm] = & -\expo{\ic\pi s}\bracks{%
{\rm P.V.}\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{s - 1} \over x^{2} - 1}{\dd x \over 2\pi\ic} +
\ic\pi\pars{{1 \over 2}{1 \over 2\pi\ic}}}
\\[2mm] & +
\expo{-\ic\pi s}\bracks{%
{\rm P.V.}\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{s - 1} \over x^{2} - 1}{\dd x \over 2\pi\ic} -
\ic\pi\pars{{1 \over 2}{1 \over 2\pi\ic}}}
\\[5mm] = &
-{\sin\pars{\pi s} \over \pi}\,
{\rm P.V.}\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{s - 1} \over x^{2} - 1}\dd x - {1 \over 2}\cos\pars{\pi s}
\label{3}\tag{3}
\end{align}

---

(\ref{2}) and (\ref{3}) $\ds{\implies}$
\begin{align}
& {\rm P.V.}\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{s - 1} \over x^{2} - 1}\dd x =
-{\pi \over \sin\pars{\pi s}}
{1 + \cos\pars{\pi s} \over 2}
\\[5mm] = &
-{\pi \over 2\sin\pars{\pi s/2}\cos\pars{\pi s/2}}
{2\cos^{2}\pars{\pi s/2} \over 2}
\\[2mm] & = -{\pi \over 2}\cot\pars{\pi s \over 2}
\\[5mm] \stackrel{{\rm with}\ (\ref{1})}{\Large\implies} &
\bbox[5px,#ffd]{%
\left.{\rm P.V.}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{s - 1}\,{a^{2} \over x^{2} - a^{2}}\,\dd x
\,\right\vert_{\substack{a\ \in\ \mathbb{R}
\\[1mm]
\Re(s)\ \in\ (0,2)}}}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbox[5px,#ffd]{-{\pi \over 2}%
\cot\pars{\pi s \over 2}\verts{a}^{s}}
\end{align}

[image]